# How can I convert a LinkedHashSet to an EnumSet in Java?

Tags: java, spring, set, neo4j, javabeans

I am trying to make a bean for converting `LinkedHashSet` into an `EnumSet`.  This is required because Neo4j needs a conversion class for this situation. I have implemented the class so far as:

```
public class LinkedHashSetToEnumSet implements Converter<LinkedHashSet<Access>, EnumSet<Access>> {

    @Override
    public EnumSet<Access> convert(LinkedHashSet<Access> h) {
        EnumSet<Access> e = new EnumSet<Access>(); // error here
        // Somehow do a for loop to add all of e to h?
        return e;
    }

}
```

I get an error where I have the commented line `// error here` where the error is:

`Cannot instantiate the type EnumSet<Resource.Access>`

Is there some simple thing that I am missing here for creating an `EnumSet`?

EDIT:

Is it possible to convert a `HashSet` into an `EnumSet`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The error is clear: `EnumSet` doesn't have constructors, the only way to create one is using the static methods in the class, that receive actual enum values. If you need to create an `EnumSet` with all of the elements in a `LinkedHashSet`, try this:

```
public EnumSet<Access> convert(LinkedHashSet<Access> h) {
    return EnumSet.copyOf(h)
}
```

I don't think it's necessary to have a class and a method for this, simply call [`copyOf()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html#copyOf%28java.util.Collection%29) whenever necessary and pass as a parameter any `Collection` of enum values.

Comment: It is because I am trying to store an EnumSet in my Neo4j repository.  I need to have a conversion class.

Comment: WARNING: `EnumSet.copyOf` throws `IllegalArgumentException` if its argument is an empty collection! That's how it gets away with not requiring a `Class` argument.